# How to show floating menu icon?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to make floating menu appears on clicking three bar icon. I've set property to app:showAsAction="never". This property get hide all the menus but it need to appear it on clicking three bars icon.

How to do it?

main_menu.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/Black"
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            android:title="Black colour"
            app:showAsAction="never"
        />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/Blue"
            android:orderInCategory="2"
            android:title="Blue colour"
            app:showAsAction="never"
        />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/Red"
            android:orderInCategory="2"
            android:title="Red colour"
            app:showAsAction="never"
        />
    </group>

</menu>
```

MainActivivity.java:

```
package com.example.zohaib.overflowmenu;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.zohaib.overflowmenu.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: app:showAsAction="never" controls options in action bar, allowing to eventually show them in action overflow (in your case all options should be in action overflow). What do you mean with three bars button? If you mean navigation drawer, menu you are defining is not the one controlling drawer content.

Answer (score 1):

Add the view to your layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Then Add the following code to `onCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(getTitle());

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i don't want to put FloatingActionButton

Comment: @ZohaibSiddique sorry what did you want

Comment: I just need toolbar to appear on right side to action bar. When i click on it, there will be item list appear.

Comment: Maybe do you mean Navigation drawer?

Comment: I mean Floating Menus